# Vb.Net Array Error

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to randomize an array and present it in RichTextBox, but I am getting the error : "Value of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable(Of String)' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'." for the last line of the code: 
My Code is below:

```
Dim List = RichTextBox1.Lines
Dim MyRnd As New System.Random
Dim MyRandomArray = List.OrderBy(Function() MyRnd.Next)
RichTextBox1.Lines = MyRandomArray
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: `Dim MyRandomArray = List.OrderBy(Function() MyRnd.Next).ToArray()`